# Listen to icon/title changes in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, events, listener, jtabbedpane

Is there a way in Swing where we can listen to events like change of icon/title in `JTabbedPane`?

### Edit 1:

As suggested by [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) tried adding a `propertyChangeListener` but icon changes are not notified.

The code that I tried is as follows:

```
final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    String property = evt.getPropertyName();
    System.out.println("property -> " + property);
  }
});

tabbedPane.insertTab("title", someIcon, null, null, 0);

final JButton changeIconBtn = new JButton("Change Icon");
changeIconBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
   tabbedPane.setIconAt(0, newIcon);
  }
});
```

If I try pressing the <kbd>Change Icon</kbd> button, the listener is not called.

Anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using a PropertyChangeListener

Comment: No, I am not sure how it works. Thanks for the pointer, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: This has the distinct odor of bad design.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Thanks for helping me improve my question. And my edits overwrote your edits by mistake, but I've added them back. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MadProgrammer said, you can use the `addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener)` method of `AccessibleContext`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TabbedPaneAccessibleTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.getAccessibleContext().addPropertyChangeListener(
        new PropertyChangeListener() {
      @Override public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        String property = evt.getPropertyName();
        System.out.println("property -> " + property);
        if (evt.getOldValue() instanceof Icon
            && evt.getNewValue() instanceof Icon) {
          System.out.println("New Icon: " + evt.getNewValue());
        }
      }
    });
    Icon someIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    Component c = Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(320, 240));
    tabbedPane.insertTab("title", someIcon, c, null, 0);

    JButton changeIconBtn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Change Icon") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        Icon newIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
        tabbedPane.setIconAt(0, newIcon);
      }
    });

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(tabbedPane));
    p.add(changeIconBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new TabbedPaneAccessibleTest().makeUI());
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @aterai for giving more insights. This helped me.